# Help identifying the model and year of this classic steel, women's bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

So what particular model is it? From what year? Any other details you know?

[image]https://photos.app.goo.gl/TgDG6ab1lDOv7S3G2

Comment: Please include the picture(s) in your post. You have enough rep to be able to do that.

Comment: it won't let me. I'm guessing it's because google photos uses short urls that don't include .jpg hence the code says no for security reasons. Says format not supported. Android uses jpg as do many digital cameras

Comment: yeah excuse the mess i;ve made in my man cave.

Comment: There's relatively little to distinguish the bike.  The chainring is the obvious identifier, but otherwise it's a good quality steel bike a few decades old.  The cottered crank suggests before the late 70s, and the lugged steel frame suggests before around 2000, but there's not much else to go on.

Answer (score 5):

The bike was manufactured by BSA, the chainring is an obvious clue, it's also a "ladies" model (parallel top tube). Looks very similar [this](https://function88.wordpress.com/2015/11/23/bsa-wayfarer-c-1975/) 1975 BSA Wayfarer. The linked post has a lot of detailed photos you can compare the frame to. Pay attention to chainring with BSA letters, arrows on chormed fork crown, rear dropouts and dropout eyelets, tube taper at seatstay/seatpost junction.

Here's how I went with search: "lettered chainring", "sprocket with letters", "bsa retro bicycle ladies", "bsa bikes retro catalog", "1970 bsa wayfarer".

Comment: looool I didn't notice th lettering on the chain ring. However whilest googling around for inner tubes I found out about the BSA brand. Partially thanks to the partially in-tact decal on the seat tube.

Answer (score 2):

If it has a Sturmey Archer gear hub, it will be date stamped, which may help dating the bike.

Comment: Excellent observation.  The bike appears to have a derailleur hanger, but there's another on the Non-drive side, so thats probably a strut mount for a full mudguard (fender) and the fitted guard is broken off short by the looks of the end.  Also, follow the dirtier-while cable outer from the left-hand, and down below the chainring it has some fitment.  The left hand may be a brake lever that is hidden, or it could be a change lever and the bike has only a front caliper brake, plus perhaps a coaster brake in the hub.   +1 for good spotting, and welcome to Stack Exchange.   Also check out [tour]

Comment: Thanks. On the BSA Wayfarer I am restoring for a family member, (and the reason I came across this), that detail is indeed the mudguard stay mount. Also used for the rear pannier in my case. I think as a "utilty" bike" / roadster, these were only ever built with SA AW hubs. Thanks for the welcome. Already familiar with Stack Exchange from 10 years on StackOverflow. Will be sure to check for "local" etiquette.